# How to call GetClassInfo with a retrieved ATOM (or is it necessary)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to simply find out, and list, as much as I can about a window. I'm getting the window via `FindWindow` with the name of the window I'm curious about, then calling `GetWindowInfo` on that window handle to fill a `WINDOWINFO` structure. At this point, I get interesting information, but I'm unsure what to do with the `WINDOWINFO.atomWindowType`. I've read I can convert it to an LPCTSTR, but it must be in the low-order word component, whereas the high-order word must be zero. I'm not sure A.) how to make this conversion, and B.) what all I can extract from having gotten an ATOM from a window. I've seem the function `GetClassInfo` which I would like to call, but I'm not sure how to do the conversion, and from my reading it almost sounds like I wouldn't be able to get info out of it. Can someone guide me or provide an example of calling `GetClassInfo` with an `ATOM`, if it is possible, and hopefully in that example provide how to do the conversion to an LPCTSTR (which I've read is a `const char*`, and I wasn't able to make that dynamically). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MAKEINTATOM` macro to convert the atom to a string pointer that can be passed to `GetClassInfo`. As for what you can do with the atom? Well, you can pass it to `GetClassInfo` or other functions that use class names. That's about it.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691909/is-it-improper-to-call-getclassinfo-from-a-hinstance-to-an-external-window