# Is it improper to call GetClassInfo from a HINSTANCE to an external window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

As a forward, I'm very inexperienced with windows API. I'm trying to learn about info about different windows, so I'm at `ATOM`s from windows, and I'm trying to call `GetClassInfo`, however it's failing each time I call it. I am trying to look at an `Untitled - Notepad` window I have open on the side. This is the code I'm using, I'm not sure if either it's improper to call GetClassInfo from an ATOM I don't really own, or if something else is going on. I'm simply trying to read out information about window attributes. Here's the code I have now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* window_name = "Untitled - Notepad";
    unsigned int window_name_length = strlen(window_name) + 1;
    wchar_t* transformed_window_name = new wchar_t[window_name_length];
    unsigned int number_of_characters_transformed;

    mbstowcs_s(&number_of_characters_transformed, transformed_window_name, window_name_length, window_name, window_name_length);
    HWND handle_to_window = FindWindow(NULL, transformed_window_name);

    WINDOWINFO window_info;
    if (!GetWindowInfo(handle_to_window, &window_info))
    {
        std::cout << "GetWindowInfo failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }

    LPTSTR my_atom_lptstr = MAKEINTATOM(window_info.atomWindowType);

    HINSTANCE hinstance_to_window = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(handle_to_window, GWL_HINSTANCE);

    WNDCLASS my_wnd_class;

    if (!GetClassInfo(hinstance_to_window, my_atom_lptstr, &my_wnd_class))
    {
        std::cout << "GetClassInfo failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* learn info from my_wnd_class */

    return 0;
}
```

I get error 1411 which is ERROR_CLASS_DOES_NOT_EXIST, but I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: So, what's the error code?

Comment: I get error code 1411, which is ERROR_CLASS_DOES_NOT_EXIST. I would assume Notepad would have a window class. I think I read somewhere I had to be the creator of the class to view it, but that doesn't seem to make sense to me, but maybe that's what it is.

Comment: AFAIK, `GetClassInfo()` does not work across process boundaries. To do that, you will likely have to inject code into the target process to call `GetClassInfo()` locally and then use IPC to send the details back to your main app.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to call `mbstowcs_s()` if you use `FindWindowA()` instead of `FindWindow()`.

Comment: Doing this cross-process is the problem.  Window handles have desktop scope, necessary so process can send messages to each other.  But the window class and the atom table where this atom is stored for this window are per-process.  Not your process.  So this is supposed to fail and you gave no hint whatsoever why you think you need to do this.   Universal answer is to use UI Automation.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if a function returns a pointer (e.g. `WNDCLASS::lpfnWndProc`), it doesn't work cross-process. You can get some of the information though, by using other APIs, e. g. [GetClassName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx), I've used it cross-process. [GetClassLong(hwnd, nIndex)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633580(v=vs.85).aspx) may also work for some values of `nIndex` (not tried).

Comment: window class name is unique only inside process. different processes can have window classes with same name (as example 2 different notepads register 2 same name window classes). as result `GetClassInfo` return information only about classes in current process. also  `GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)` will be work only in 32bit windows. on 64bit - you need have own application 64-bit and use `GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE);` also you can call `GetClassLongPtrW(hwnd, GCLP_WNDPROC);` for example for get class data instead `GetClassInfo`